# Docker Image: Atmospheric Correction in Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, jupyter-notebook, docker

Following https://github.com/gee-community/ee-jupyter-contrib/tree/master/docker/atmcorr-ee I was able to build and run docker. And to authenticate and git clone, but while:

```
cd gee-atmcorr-S2/jupyer_notebooks/
jupyter-notebook sentinel2_atmospheric_correction.ipynb --ip='*' --port=8888 --allow-root
```

then I got:

```
root@9c6555522c26:/gee-atmcorr-S2/jupyer_notebooks# jupyter-notebook sentinel2_atmospheric_correction.ipynb --ip='*' --port=8888 --allow-root
[I 20:18:29.195 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'allow_remote_access'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 864, in _default_allow_remote
    addr = ipaddress.ip_address(self.ip)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/ipaddress.py", line 54, in ip_address
    address)
ValueError: '' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "</miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1628, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1378, in init_webapp
    self.jinja_environment_options,
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 159, in __init__
    default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 252, in init_settings
    allow_remote_access=jupyter_app.allow_remote_access,
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 867, in _default_allow_remote
    for info in socket.getaddrinfo(self.ip, self.port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Any hint on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an issue in the Jupyter Notebook 5.6.0 release. The fix suggested in [jupyter/notebook#3946](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3946) is to use:

`--ip='0.0.0.0'` for IPv4 or `--ip='::'` for IPv6.